# Column type differes between table and view

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a database as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ... (other fields)
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And a view defined like that:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view` AS SELECT 
  `id` AS `id` 
  ... (other fields)
  FROM `table`
```

Now when I execute `show columns in table` I get:

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+
| id              | int(11)          | NO   | PRI |
...
```

But the `show columns in view` shows this:

```
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+
| Field            | Type                | Null | Key |
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+
| id               | bigint(11)          | YES  |     |
...
```

Now why did the column `id` went from being `int(11)` to `bigint(11)` and how, if possible, can I make it so that it stays as `int(11)`?

**EDIT:** Added view modifiers that are between `CREATE` and `VIEW` in case they could help in any way

Comment: Why do you even use `id` AS `id`  if id is exactly what you want it to be from original table? Whats the point of the view then at all?

Comment: This is a simplified version as indicated by the `...`. The actual view in the database has dozens of fields and joins a few tables but that doesn't affect the resulting type change